# Sympy Subs, Replace, and Xreplace not working with expressions

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to substitute an expression that is the output of a solved system of equations and am getting errors.

```
q,a,b,c=symbols('q,a,b,c')
def p(q):
    return a-b*q
some_equation=eqn1-eqn2
new_equation=sol(some_equation,q)
```

New equation returns

```
[(a-c)/(2*b)]
```

when I use p(q).subs(q,new_equation) I get p(q) and return gives me a type error no matter what I do. Xreplace throws a Sympify error. Any suggestions to get what should be a simple sub to work???

Comment: Not familiar with sympy, but it might help to provide the full text of the error or a complete runnable example of code that produces the error.

Answer (score 2):

Sympy's `solve` always returns a Python list of solutions. There can be zero, one or multiple solutions to a general equation.  `subs` needs one concrete value from the list, it can not work with the list as a whole.  Therefore, you need to iterate through the list to do the substitutions. If you are certain that there is only one solution, you can just use `solutions[0]`:

```py
from sympy import symbols, solve, Eq

q, a, b, c = symbols('q a b c')

def p(q):
    return a - b * q

some_equation = p(q) - c
solutions = solve(some_equation, q)
print("solutions:", solutions)
for sol in solutions:
    print("solution for q =", sol, " --> p(q) =", p(q).subs(q, sol))
```

Output:

```
solutions: [(a - c)/b]
solution for q = (a - c)/b  --> p(q) = c
```

Note that instead of writing `p` as a function of q, you can also write it directly as a sympy expression: `p = a - b * q`. Also note that although you can write the equation as `some_equation = p(q) - c`, sympy's canonical way to write such equations is `some_equation = Eq(p(q), c)`.

Here is another example, which has two solutions. It also uses `simplify()` because more complicated expressions by default are only simplified just a little bit.

```py
p = a * q ** 2 + b * q
some_equation = Eq(p, c)
solutions = solve(some_equation, q)
print("solutions:", solutions)
for sol in solutions:
    print("solution for q =", sol, " --> p(q) =", p.subs(q, sol).simplify())
```

Output:

```
solutions: [(-b + sqrt(4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a), -(b + sqrt(4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)]
solution for q = (-b + sqrt(4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)  --> p(q) = c
solution for q = -(b + sqrt(4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)  --> p(q) = c
```